# How to install Freemind in Void Linux

Tags: package-management, void-linux

I am using [Void Linux](https://voidlinux.org/) which is otherwise working very well. However, I cannot find [Freemind](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/freemind) package in its [repositories](https://voidlinux.org/packages/). How can I install Freemind in Void Linux? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work here.

Download the .zip from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freemind/) and extract it to a folder called freemind.

Open that freemind directory in your terminal and do the following:

```
chmod +x ./freemind.sh
./freemind.sh
```

Then let it do its thing.

You can make various system shortcuts to the command as needed.